How to install and update only the firefox package from Mozilla repository in Debian but keep the firefox-esr from Debian stable repository?
context
I usually use Debian 12 (bookworm) with the .tar archive of Firefox downloaded from Mozilla web site, decompressed and copied in /opt/firefox/, since I want an updated version of Firefox and not having to rely on Firefox ESR provided by Debian.
what I want to achieve
I want to try to use the Mozilla packages repository (deb https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla main), so that I can manage Firefox updates via apt or synaptic instead of having it auto-updates by itself.
The problem is that firefox-esr package is present in both Debian stable and Mozilla repositories.
what I did
I tried to setup priorities with pinning, but I'm not sure I configured them right.
This is my /etc/apt/source.list file:
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-backports main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.gpg] https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla main

(I removed all the comments and empty lines to keep it short, the packages.mozilla.org.gpg key is correctly installed in /usr/share/keyrings/, apt-get update command works correclty)
And this is my 99mozilla file I created in /etc/apt/preferences.d:
# Never prefer packages from the Mozilla repository
Package: *
Pin: origin packages.mozilla.org
Pin-Priority: 1

# Allow upgrading only firefox from Mozilla repository
Package: firefox
Pin: origin packages.mozilla.org
Pin-Priority: 500

The output of apt-cache policy command is:
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
   1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main all Packages
     release o=namespaces/moz-fx-productdelivery-pr-38b5/repositories/mozilla,a=mozilla,n=mozilla,l=namespaces/moz-fx-productdelivery-pr-38b5/repositories/mozilla,c=main,b=all
     origin packages.mozilla.org
   1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     release o=namespaces/moz-fx-productdelivery-pr-38b5/repositories/mozilla,a=mozilla,n=mozilla,l=namespaces/moz-fx-productdelivery-pr-38b5/repositories/mozilla,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.mozilla.org
 100 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=stable-backports,n=bookworm-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 100 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=stable-backports,n=bookworm-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 100 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=stable-backports,n=bookworm-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/non-free-firmware amd64 Packages
     release v=12-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bookworm-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free-firmware,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=12-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bookworm-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=12-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bookworm-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bookworm-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/non-free-firmware amd64 Packages
     release v=12,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bookworm-security,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free-firmware,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=12,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bookworm-security,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bookworm-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/non-free-firmware amd64 Packages
     release v=12.6,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Debian,c=non-free-firmware,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=12.6,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=12.6,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.6,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
Pinned packages:
     firefox -> 129.0.2~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 129.0.1~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 129.0~build2 with priority 500
     firefox -> 128.0.3~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 128.0.2~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 128.0~build2 with priority 500
     firefox -> 127.0.2~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 127.0.1~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 127.0~build2 with priority 500
     firefox -> 126.0.1~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 126.0~build2 with priority 500
     firefox -> 125.0.3~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 125.0.2~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 125.0.1~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 124.0.2~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 124.0.1~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 124.0~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 123.0.1~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 123.0~build3 with priority 500
     firefox -> 122.0.1~build1 with priority 500
     firefox -> 122.0~build2 with priority 500

question
Is the configuration I implemented correct?
In particular:

Will only the firefox package be installed from Mozilla repository and not, for example, firefox-esr?
Will the package firefox be upgraded with future apt-get upgrade command?
If everything is correct (yes to both questions before) I imagine that also all dependencies for the firefox package will be installed from debian repositories (if it is possible to resolve them), is that right?

I'm asking confirmation because I'm worried I'm going to break my debian installation. Thank you.
update
As requested I post the output for apt policy firefox-esr command:
firefox-esr:
  Installed: 115.14.0esr-1~deb12u1
  Candidate: 115.14.0esr-1~deb12u1
  Version table:
     128.1.0esr~build2 1
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     128.0esr~build2 1
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
 *** 115.14.0esr-1~deb12u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     115.12.0esr-1~deb12u1 500
        500 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages

And for for apt policy firefox:
firefox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 129.0.2~build1
  Version table:
     129.0.2~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     129.0.1~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     129.0~build2 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     128.0.3~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     128.0.2~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     128.0~build2 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     127.0.2~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     127.0.1~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     127.0~build2 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     126.0.1~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     126.0~build2 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     125.0.3~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     125.0.2~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     125.0.1~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     124.0.2~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     124.0.1~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     124.0~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     123.0.1~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     123.0~build3 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     122.0.1~build1 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages
     122.0~build2 500
          1 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages


Your configuration is fine. apt policy shows priority 1 for the Mozilla repository, except for the firefox package which is pinned at 500. This is confirmed by the apt policy output for the firefox and firefox-esr packages individually: the former is selected at priority 500 across all versions (so the latest version wins), the latter is selected at priority 500 only from the Debian repositories.
